# Camera being used by another application

Tags: webcam

I am trying to test my webcam, as I am having problems with it. I just asked a question on why the "Set as default" option wasn't there for my camera, but I don't know if this is related. I am using webcamtests.com, and when I try to test my camera, it says it is being used by another application. I downloaded process explorer and apparently it's being used by explorer.exe. I don't want to end this task, because I think it will do something I don't know how to fix. The end result I'm looking for is to use the webcam in OBS, but when I select it, the video just freezes as it's being used by something else. What should I do?

Comment: Not that this is what you need, but I test my webcam in windows using the built in camera app first.  This eliminates to possibility of having browser permission issues and the like.  Does the behavior occur when using the built in camera app?  Oh.. and you hit the little spinny arrow thing to switch cameras.

Comment: If Skype is installed, see [this article](https://www.techbout.com/webcam-is-being-used-by-another-application-windows-10-45267/). Otherwise, verify that you're using the latest bios and chip-set update from the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is another application on your computer that is using the webcam already.

I would suggest a full restart on your computer (not shutdown) and then the first thing you do when you login is launch the Camera APP on your computer.

Click on the windows icon at the bottom left and type away Camera or  Scroll down to C on your program list when you click on the bottom left windows icon.

Test and see if you can see yourself, If you can then close out camera app and only launch OBS by itself without the browser open or any other application. Then test the camera there.

Keep us posted!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried this, and I got an error code from camera that meant another application is using the camera.